# New command based on command name

Tags: macros

I had this idea that would save me a considerable amount of time in writing my thesis. Here's the deal:
I need to typeset lots of equations with vectors and matrices in them. I'd like my vectors in boldface, lowercase and my matrices in boldface, uppercase. For a vectors and matrices I've defined the following in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\v}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\ensuremath{\boldsymbol{\uppercase{#1}}}}
```

In context, I use \v{x} to typeset a vector x, etc.

However, wouldn't it be nice to be able to typeset `\vx` to create that same vector **x**. Then, if I'm writing about a vector **a**, **b** and **c**, I can just write `\va`, `\vb` and `\vc`.

Is this possible in LaTeX?

Comment: It is possible to define all those macros but you could just do `\v a` and it would work without any extra definitions at all also note that for latin letters `\mathbf{a}` _much_ more efficient than `\boldsymbol{a}` which has to generate a new math list and set the argument four times in different styles before choosing which to use.

Comment: I'd recommend against using command names such as `\vx`, `\vy` and so on. You're bound to forget very soon their meaning. I *surely* recommend against using `\ensuremath` for this kind of application. Use `\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}` (loading the `bm` package). Do *not* redefine `\v` (`\vec` is safe, instead).

Comment: Running off of @egreg's suggestion, if the length of typing is the issue, I would just go ahead and actually *do* the `\va`, `\vb`, etc. (not necessarily defining them) and then just doing a regex-replace on them when you're ready to compile.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sounds like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use extensively bold math italic for your vectors and matrices, the best solution is to define a new symbol font:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbmit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
```

and then doing

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbmit{#1}}
\let\matr\vec
```

(or, in the "macho programmer way", `\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbmit}`). If a matrix is called "A", there is little sense in inputting it as `\matr{a}`, in my opinion.

Abbreviations such as `\va`, `\vb` and so on *can* be defined, but the biggest risk is to forget the commands' meaning in a short time. If you *really* want to follow this path, then here's how:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbmit}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbmit{#1}}
\let\matr\vec

\makeatletter
\@tfor\next:=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyxz\do
 {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@namedef{v\next}{\noexpand\vec{\next}}%
  }\x}
\@tfor\next:=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\do
 {\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\@namedef{m\next}{\noexpand\matr{\next}}%
  }\x}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is a vector $\vx$ and this is a matrix $\mA$.

This is a vector $\vec{x}$ and this is a matrix $\matr{A}$.

Also $\matr{\Gamma}$ works.
\end{document}
```

Using `\ensuremath` is, in my opinion, wrong, as these are mathematical entities and so they should always be in explicit math mode.

[image]